# getBooleanSmart better parser

Tags: java, preferences

In a lot of places (200 in our main data base and more in other) we have config that are boolean.

We have special function that accepts a default and the current config that can be null. If null return default. If not try with out strings (Y for yes) else pass to java Boolean

What is acceptable : y, yes, 1, true (case insensitive)

All projects I have worked for have needed something like this.

We do not have a drop down everywhere due to some prefs belonging to a common framework and are rendered as text boxes along with a description.

Questions:
1. if you have many boolean what is your strategy - custom function or only use what is there by Java?
2. Dont you think the java Boolean should accept y as true too as so many people enter that as true (or yes)

Not using java.util.prefs.Preferences but there too " Valid strings are "true", which represents true, and "false", which represents false. Case is ignored,"

Better parser - not about code optomize but about having more features - that of recognizing general human words that mean true

Answer (score 1):

Your question lends itself to opinion, but I will try and avoid that -

1) It depends on the requirements of the application.

2) The fact is that java Boolean does not behave that way (and it would be very English focused if it did). For example, the French for yes is oui, the German is ja and the Russian is da.

Finally, code that converts your "truthy" String(s) into Boolean(s) is almost certainly not a critical path. Please don't [optimize prematurely](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), it's evil.

Comment: About last comment : what do you mean - dont have a utility to convert a string to a bool? even if its used in 5 different places (other classes)? reason : some places we parse our own props from data base, other we parse user input, and in others we parse what we go from customer files

Comment: agree with point 1 and 2 -> just english aint good enough but did not get the advice in the last

Comment: I'm saying don't worry about optimizing your utility class, until you have profiler or other metrics that demonstrate it is having a meaningful impact on the performance of your application.

Comment: oh not trying to optomize it. this question came up as i was working on a new project wher they not using this and the admin guy and i were wondering why something was not working... it was because his yes in a few config were not parsing as true